# Kafka Zookeeper Connection drop continuously

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I have setup Kafka 3-node cluster and Zookeeper 3-node cluster, on separate nodes. Using Kafka I can produce and consume messages successfully and run commands like `kafka-topic.sh` to get topic lists and their informations from Zookeeper, but there are some errors on Kafka `server.log` file. The following warning appears continuously:

```
[2018-02-18 21:50:01,241] WARN Client session timed out, have not heard from server in 320190154ms for sessionid 0x161a94b101f0001 (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2018-02-18 21:50:01,242] INFO Client session timed out, have not heard from server in 320190154ms for sessionid 0x161a94b101f0001, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2018-02-18 21:50:01,343] INFO zookeeper state changed (Disconnected) (org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient)
[2018-02-18 21:50:01,989] INFO Opening socket connection to server zookeeper3/192.168.1.206:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error) (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2018-02-18 21:50:02,008] INFO Socket connection established to zookeeper3/192.168.1.206:2181, initiating session (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2018-02-18 21:50:02,042] INFO Session establishment complete on server zookeeper3/192.168.1.206:2181, sessionid = 0x161a94b101f0001, negotiated timeout = 6000 (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2018-02-18 21:50:02,042] INFO zookeeper state changed (SyncConnected) (org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient)
[2018-02-18 21:59:31,570] INFO [Group Metadata Manager on Broker 102]: Removed 0 expired offsets in 0 milliseconds. (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupMetadataManager)
```

It seems the Kafka sessions in zookeeper expires periodically!

In Zookeeper logs are the following warninngs, too:

```
2018-02-18 18:20:06,149 [myid:1] - WARN  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxn@368] - caught end of stream exception
EndOfStreamException: Unable to read additional data from client sessionid 0x161a94b101f0001, likely client has closed socket
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn.doIO(NIOServerCnxn.java:239)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory.run(NIOServerCnxnFactory.java:203)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2018-02-18 18:20:06,151 [myid:1] - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxn@1044] - Closed socket connection for client /192.168.1.203:43162 which had sessionid 0x161a94b101f0001
2018-02-18 18:20:06,781 [myid:1] - WARN  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxn@368] - caught end of stream exception
EndOfStreamException: Unable to read additional data from client sessionid 0x161a94b101f0002, likely client has closed socket
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn.doIO(NIOServerCnxn.java:239)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory.run(NIOServerCnxnFactory.java:203)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2018-02-18 18:20:06,782 [myid:1] - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxn@1044] - Closed socket connection for client /192.168.1.201:45330 which had sessionid 0x161a94b101f0002
2018-02-18 18:37:29,127 [myid:1] - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxnFactory@192] - Accepted socket connection from /192.168.1.202:52480
2018-02-18 18:37:29,139 [myid:1] - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:ZooKeeperServer@942] - Client attempting to establish new session at /192.168.1.202:52480
2018-02-18 18:37:29,143 [myid:1] - INFO  [CommitProcessor:1:ZooKeeperServer@687] - Established session 0x161a94b101f0003 with negotiated timeout 30000 for client /192.168.1.202:52480
2018-02-18 18:37:29,432 [myid:1] - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxn@1044] - Closed socket connection for client /192.168.1.202:52480 which had sessionid 0x161a94b101f0003
```

I think it's because zookeeper can't get heartbeat from Kafka nodes. The followings are Zookeeper `zoo.cfg`:

```
tickTime=2000
dataDir=/var/zookeeper/
clientPort=2181
initLimit=5
syncLimit=2
server.1=zookeeper1:2888:3888
server.2=zookeeper2:2888:3888
server.3=zookeeper3:2888:3888
```

and Kafka `server.properties` customized setting:

```
broker.id=1
listeners = PLAINTEXT://kafka1:9092
num.partitions=24
delete.topic.enable=true
default.replication.factor=2
log.dirs=/data/kafka/data
zookeeper.connect=zookeeper1:2181,zookeeper2:2181,zookeeper3:2181
log.retention.hours=168
```

I use the same zookeeper cluster for Hadoop HA without any problem. I think there is something wrong with the Kafka properties **listeners** and **advertised.listeners**. I read the Kafka documentation but couldn't understand their meaning.

In the host file of all OSes, hostnames such that `zookeeper1` to `zookeeper3` and `kafka1` to `kafka3` are defined and reachable through ping command. I removed the following lines from hosts:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       hostname
```

I think it couldn't cause the problem.

- Kafka version: 0.11
- Zookeeper version: 3.4.10

Can anyone help?

Comment: were you able to figure out what was the issue? I'm running into similar issue. Re-starting kafka broker works but its just a temporary solution.

Comment: I guess it's because of Java GC and during GC, brokers can't heartbeat Zookeeper.

Comment: have you found solution for it even , i am facing same problem can ay one help with it @SoheilPourbafrani

Comment: have you found solution for it even , i am facing same problem can ay one help with it @BandiKishore

Comment: @andani Yes, as Soheil pointed out, When I verified the GC Logs, there was major GC running continuously. This was because of a memory leak bug in kafka w.r.t. metrics. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-6307

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We were facing a similar issue with Kafka. As @Soheil pointed out it was due to a Major GC running.

When a Major GC runs, then Kafka would sometimes not be able to send heartbeat to zookeeper. For us the Major GC was running almost once every 15 sec. On taking a heap dump, we realized it was due to a Metric Memory Leak in [Kafka](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-6529).